# How to get multiple ints from a single textfield

Tags: java

I have a textfield and I need to get ints from it

the user will input something like 1, 2, 3 and it needs to return all three numbers

Any help?

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to get a single int? Please provide a minimal code snap

Comment: You will probably have to "split" it first with the Java String.split() method.  There are other ways of course.

Comment: I have this for returning a single int


ID = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

Comment: You can use String::split and Integer::parseInt

Comment: Why not use multiple JTextFields? You can easily put them into a JPanel in a grid using a GridLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
  String[] strings = jTextField.getText().split( ", *" );
  int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
  for( int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) 
     ints[i] = Integer.parseInt( strings[i].trim() );
```

The code, and the regex, is untested however.

Comment: `split(",")` should be more then enough and you will need to `trim` the resulting elements to ensure they don't contain white space

Comment: You're right, `parseInt()` doesn't like spaces.  I added a call to `trim()`.  I left the `", *"` in though because there's a chance trim() will do no work if the regex can remove all the unneeded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use StringTokenizer for this.

Suppose a user entered `1, 2, 3` :

```
String got = "1, 2, 3"  //input from user
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(got, ',');
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
}
```

Comment: *"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead"* - [`StringTokenizer` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: You are right. deleting my answer. I was to use regex for this but I thought user will get this quickly, because it doesn't need to have any knowlegde of regex and it will be easier. I must have mention this in my answer. @MadProgrammer

Comment: No don't delete it. It is good to know how/why not to do something as well as how to do it. I didn't know StringTokenizer was being phased out either.